# Scala: companion objects from subclasses

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I want to create a companion object that is subclass of a parameterized base class, and *only* fixes the base classes parameter -- that is, all methods are inherited from the base class.

One way to do this is with a trait:

```
class Foo(v: Int, printStream: PrintStream) {
  def print: Unit = printStream.println(v);
}

trait FooFactory {
  protected val printsTo: PrintStream

  def apply(v: Int) = new Foo(v, printsTo)
  def makeFoo(v: Int) = apply(v)
}

object Foo extends FooFactory {
  protected val printsTo: PrintStream = System.out
}

val foo = Foo(3)
foo.print
val f2 = Foo.makeFoo(2)
f2.print
```

This way seems cleaner, but Intellij seems to think the base class methods are inaccessible outside the compilation unit (the .scala file that defines the companion):

```
class Bar(v: Int, printStream: PrintStream) {
  def print: Unit = printStream.println(v);
}

class BarFactory(printsTo: PrintStream) {
  def apply(v: Int) = new Bar(v, printsTo)
  def makeBar(v: Int) = apply(v)
}

object Bar extends BarFactory(System.out) {}

val bar = Bar(3)
bar.print
val b2 = Bar.makeBar(2)
b2.print
```

Are these effectively equivalent (except for the name change Foo => Bar, of course)? Is one preferable?

The intent is to give the companion object a default PrintStream, while allowing users to create other factories if they need to:

```
val BarLoggerFactory = new BarFactory(someLogPrintStream)
val bar3 = BarLoggerFactory.makeBar(3);
```

Comment: I pasted your first snippet on a Scala _2.12.8_ **RELP**, using a `package` block, and it worked. Did you tried compiling your code with **SBT**, **Maven** or **Gradle** or any tool that uses a real Scala _compiler_ instead of **Intellij**, if so what error message did you get ? - sometimes **Intellij** fails without any reason.

Comment: `class Foo(v: Int, printStream: PrintStream = System.out)` perhaps?

Comment: Probably your issue is a bit more complicated because I can't reproduce it even inside the Idea. Putting all the `Foo`/`FooFactory`/`Bar`/`BarFactory` in `Foo.scala` and the last 4 lines with their usage into `Main.scala` Idea doesn't complain about anything anywhere (except for warnings about not defining the return type for public methods and a `;` in `Foo.scala`). Do I miss something? Where exactly Idea complains for you and what about?